# WUSA.exe not working while installing update?

Tags: powershell

i am using powershell to install windows update on a machine. I am using below command line to achieve so.

```
wusa.exe "file_path" \norestart \quiet
```

The update is not getting installed and throwing an error:

Windows update  could not be installed because of error 2147942487 "The parameter is incorrect." (Command line: ""C:\windows\system32\wusa.exe"  d:\riteshthakur\abc.msu \quiet \norestart")

AM i doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a forward slash for your parameters in Windows, typically:

```
wusa.exe "file_path" /norestart /quiet
```

Additionally, if you're having problems, try using the log parameter to see what's going on:

```
wusa.exe "file_path" /norestart /quiet /log:C:\wusa.log
```

Comment: Still throwing an error: Windows update  could not be installed because of error 2359302 "" (Command line: ""C:\windows\system32\wusa.exe"  abc.msu /norestart /quiet /log:c:\wusa.log"). 
also, the log file generated (.dpx) if opened with notepad has just NULL values in it. Text file generated in encrypted.

Comment: @RiteshThakur 2359302 is hex 0x00240006, which [appears to be](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh968413(v=vs.85).aspx) "Error: already installed."

Comment: This works if i am on the machine itself, but throws an error, access denied when i try to run it from a remote machine. I have admin rights on both the machines. ?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, when running the wusa command and want to see the log make sure you save it as an .evt file which will then be opened by the windows event viewer. So from command above:

```
wusa.exe "file_path" /norestart /quiet /log:C:\wusa.evt
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).